# Azure Glassfish Connection Pooling Communications Link Failure

Tags: mysql, azure, glassfish, connection-pooling

I have just set up a new Azure MySQL.
I can connect to it via Workbench but not via Glassfish 4.1.2 connection pool.
I am testing 2 installations of Glassfish. One on my machine (without SSL) another installation on another Azure VM (with SSL). But I get Communications Link Failure with every ping on both installations. While I can ping successfully via both installations to other MySQL on other machines.

- I get my connection string from Azure portal.
- All other GF connection pool configs are by default.
- I have SSL certificate installed on Azure VM Glassfish.
- I have allowed both ip addresses on azure portal (successful workbench connection).

Is there any documentation or tutorial on Azure MySQL + Glassfish Connection Pooling config?
I can't seem to find it. Or does anyone know what I'm missing? Please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem in case anyone is interested.

I'm using ConnectorJ v.5.5 which allows username character size max limit of 16. With Azure requiring us to append @servername at the end, it was over the limit.

So I switched to Connector v.8.0.22 which allows username max of 32 characters.

However, there are extra config. to avoid "Class name is wrong or classpath is not set" error

1. put the connector 8.0.22 in glassfish-4.1.2\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib
2. when setting connection pool set Datasource Classname = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
3. in the properties change LoggerClassName = com.mysql.cj.log.StandardLogger and Logger = com.mysql.cj.log.StandardLogger
4. if you use SSL set useSSL=true otherwise set useSSL=false in the properties or connection string

cheers!